# Get selected value of dropdownlist in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

how can i get select value of dropdownlist and here is my code which is working fine.

```
    var list = new[] {   
    new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Name1" }, 
    new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Name2" }, 
    new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Name3" } 
};

var selectList = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Name", 2);
ViewData["People"] = selectList;

<%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Peoples, ViewData["People"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `model.Peoples` property which you are using in the `DropDownListFor` must be of type integer. It will be bound to the selected value in the controller action to which you are submitting this form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourModelType model)
{
    int selectedPersonId = model.Peoples;
    // TODO: do something with the id
    return View();
}
```

Remark: a more semantically correct name for the `Peoples` property would be `PersonId`.