# getting the value of dropdownlist in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new to MVC Tell me how can i retrieve the selected dropdownlist value in controller
this is how i add the values to dropdownlist

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "What is your Place of Birth?", Value = "What is your Place of Birth?" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "What is your favourite Book?", Value = "What is your favourite Book?" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "What is your childhood friend name?", Value = "What is your childhood friend name?" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "What is your first car make and model?", Value = "What is your first car make and model?" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "What is your favourite place?", Value = "What is your favourite place?" });
            ViewData["ddlitems"] = items;
```

**VIEW FILE**

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlitems")
```

Comment: Have a value for each item and add the same in your model(with same name). The MVC framework will automatically retrieve the values for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Get selected value of dropdownlist in asp.net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793585/get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

On your model, have a property for the value:

```
class ModelClass
{
    public string DropdownValue{get; set;}
}
```

Then use the following Razor syntax

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.DropdownValue, "ddItems");
```

That will create a dropdown named the same as the Model property, it should automatically post back with the model

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to get the value of the selected option is just to match the ID of the element to that which you are posting to the `ActionResult`. So if your `select` element is rendered as;

```
<select id="SomeID">
    <option value="What is your Place of Birth?">What is your Place of Birth?</option>
</select>
```

Then you post this to an `ActionResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionResult(string SomeID){
    // SomeID = What is your Place of Birth?
    Return View();
}
```

This might be the easiest option in your case because you do not have a strongly typed object which you are passing into the `View`. Also note that this will work with any form elements that you are posting. Just match up the IDs with parameters on the `ActionResult`.

To take this further, you would probably be best reading about [Model Binding within ASP.Net MVC.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)